# Sharing a property between objects

Tags: php, oop

This might sound a bit confusing, which is why I'm here as I'm probably doing something wrong. Following the logic of the example code below, I'm trying to create a "shared property" so that any class extending B can modify the property of A, and class C will have access to it.

```
class A
{
    public $shared = null;
}

class B
{
    public $a;
    public $c;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this->a = new A();
        $this->c = new C($this->a->shared);
    }
}

class C
{
    public $test;

    function __construct(&$shared)
    {
        $this->test = &$shared;

        var_dump($this->test);
    }
}

class Test extends B
{
    $this->a->shared = 'success';
}
```

The logic seems to work but my pessimism is kicking in. Am I passing this by reference correctly, or is there a better way to achieve what I'm after without passing by reference?

Comment: in OOP paradigm the objects cannot share attributes, only other objects .. also , keep in mind that setting `public` visibility would break the encapsulation of object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to pass by reference at all, as objects are inherently passed by reference in PHP >= 5.0; as long as the same instance of `A` is being used, the same value of `shared` will also be used.

Which is to say, just pass around the reference to 'A', and not to its particular member variable.

Of course, you can also play with the references directly, as you are doing in your code.  Notwithstanding the syntactic incorrectness of the `Test` class at this time, your concept is correct.  If I change the `Test` class as follows (and run):

```
class Test extends B {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct(); 
        $this->a->shared = 'success';
    }
}

var_dump(new Test);
```

I get the following output:

```
null // <-- from the first var_dump in C::__construct()

object(Test)[1]
  public 'a' => 
    object(A)[2]
      public 'shared' => &string 'success' (length=7)
  public 'c' => 
    object(C)[3]
      public 'test' => &string 'success' (length=7)
```

Am simpler example:

```
class a { public $f; }
class b { public $f; }

$a = new a;
$b = new b;

$a->f = 1;
$b->f = &$a->f;

$a->f = 2;

var_dump($a, $b);
```

produces

```
object(a)[1]
  public 'f' => &int 2
object(b)[2]
  public 'f' => &int 2
```

And you can do that as many times as you need to.  Hopefully in a better way, this is a very poor sample.

Comment: The thing is, I don't want "C" to have access to the object, only that specific property...

Comment: I find your desire strange, but I'm not here to judge.  Your code should do that just fine (with the syntactic corrections made for class `Test`) in that `C` will not have a reference to `A`, but only a reference to a member variable.  It could probably be done in a less convoluted way, but you're probably on-the-right-track enough to derive that one for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

In your current code `A::$shared` doesn't point to anything. It's null when you pass it to `C`. So you're actually passing a reference to `null`, not a reference to an object.

If you make the shared object first, you can pass it around:

```
$shared = new stdClass();

$a = new stdClass();
$b = new stdClass();
$a->shared = $shared;
$b->shared = $shared;

$shared->foo = "bar";
var_dump($a->shared->foo); // "bar"
$b->shared->foo = "baz";
var_dump($a->shared->foo); // "baz"
```

Comment: The thing is, I don't want "C" to have access to the object, only that specific property.

Comment: What do you mean? You're passing `$shared` to `C`, isn't that what you wanted? You could pass just `$shared->foo` but then you're back to the original problem.

Comment: I mean `C` should only have access to the `$shared` property and nothing more. Any other properties or methods in `A` should be off limits.

Comment: That's not an issue here. `C` doesn't magically get access rights in `A` because it was created in `A`.

Comment: I'm apologize, but I don't understand your answer. Where does the `C` object from my example apply to your example?

Answer (score -1):

Why not have B extend A, or have the property of A inside B anyways?
Also, static variables may be of help to you. If you aren't familiar with them ask the Goog.

Comment: Would you consider improving your question to provide more detail about your recommended solution and consider moving your questions and "Goog" comment to comment section below the main post?

Comment: How is suggesting that the OP extend a class not enough detail? That is the obvious solution for me, and clearly the OP knows how to do it. I see people routinely get downvoted for not researching first, and yet when I point somebody in the direction of researching static variables (which is also a viable solution), it gets downvoted? I am confused.

Comment: The first sentence isn't an answer, it is a question. The second sentence is a suggestion. It may become an answer with detail, but in its current form it is simply a pointer to a potential answer "out there somewhere." The final sentence is superfluous. You can provide links to the source documentation, or simply leave it out.